# Passing A Variable Pointer Into A Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, pointers

I am trying to update a class from within a dictionary context but the dictionary gets instantialized with the value of the class attributes not the "pointer" to the variables.

```py
class SomeClass():
    status = 0

new_entry = SomeClass()

print (new_entry.status) #prints 0 - expected

data_attribute ={
    "status":[1407,new_entry.status,0]
}
data_attribute["status"][1] = 123

print (data_attribute["status"]) # prints 123 - expected

print (new_entry.status) # prints 0 - not desired
```

The problem is I don't know how to pass a "pointer" to the class attribute "status" such that updating it in the dictionary updates it in the main class structure. I expect there is something stupid I do not understand OR I am doing this in completely the wrong way but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it that way in Python.
The usual option is to store the reference to your object and go through it to get to the attribute. This does not fit exactly in the way you wrote the code simply because there are no pointers in Python.

```
class SomeClass():
    status = 0

new_entry = SomeClass()

print (new_entry.status) #prints 0 - expected

data_attribute ={
    "status":[1407, new_entry, 0]
}
data_attribute["status"][1].status = 123

print (data_attribute["status"][1].status) # prints 123 - expected

print (new_entry.status) # prints 123 - OK
```

The following example goes better with your intentions, but is meant to make something obvious only:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.status = 0

a = A()

values = dict(a=a)
pointers = values

print(pointers['a'] is a)
print(pointers['a'].status)
print(a.status)

a.status = 1
print(pointers['a'].status)

pointers['a'].status = 2
print(a.status)
```

Note how I store the status in the instance not the class. Instance attributes hide class attributes when assigned.

Basically you use the keys of a dict as pointers. Also you don't even need `pointers` as that's nothing more than another name for the same object dict as `values`.

So it's really the dict keys that act as the pointers that you want.

Python only uses references. Any name is a reference bound to some object. Keeping track of references to immutable objects like `str` or `int` will not work as expected because if you assign new values to them in the code ahead, new objects will be created and bound to the same references (original objects can't change).